# Console output in Mongoose promise not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, mongoose

I am just working on an analysis project. I have a create method in node but I don't know why suddenly this is happening. I have connected to the database successfully. and wrote created a mongoose model successfully.Now in below code `promise.then()` is not visited. document is not created. but if I removed any required field, it throws a error as expected.

my create method:

```
create: function (doc) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            bcrypt.hash(doc.password, saltRounds).then((hash) => {
                doc.password = hash;
                console.log(doc); //works
                Account.create(doc).then((account) => {
                    console.log(account); //not working, no error, successful execution, code exit 0.
                    resolve(account);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(account); //nothing printed
                    reject(err);
                });
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(account); //nothing printed
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    }
```

my database connection in database/db.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

const database = {
    connect: function () {
        mongoose.connect(
            process.env.MONGO_URI + '?retryWrites=true',
            { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
        ).then(
            function () {
                console.log('database connected successfully');
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
};

module.exports = database;
```

My whole controller code controllers/account.js:

```
Account = require('../models/account');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;

authController = {
    create: function (doc) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            bcrypt.hash(doc.password, saltRounds).then((hash) => {
                doc.password = hash;
                let promise = Account.create(doc);
                promise.then((account) => {
                    console.log(account);
                    resolve(account);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                });
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    },
    show: function (email) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let filter = {email: email};
            Account.findOne(filter).then((account) => {
                resolve(account);
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    },
    update: function (id, update) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let filter = {_id: id};
            Account.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update).then((account) => {
                resolve(account);
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    },
    destroy: function (id) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let filter = {_id: id};
            Account.findOneAndDelete(filter).then(() => {
                resolve({deleted: true});
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    },
    compare: function (doc) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let filter = {email: doc.email};
            Account.findOne(filter).then(user => {
                bcrypt.compareSync(doc.password, user.password).then((result) => {
                    resolve(result);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    reject(err);
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    }
};


module.exports = authController;
```

My model for account in models/account.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const accountSchema = new Schema({
        first: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        last: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        role: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        boards: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Board',
            required: false
        }]
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    });

Account = mongoose.connection.model('User', accountSchema);
module.exports = Account;
```

my test.js code:

```
const accountCtrl = require('./controllers/account');
const account = {
        first: "User 1",
        last: "Last 1",
        email: "email1@tasks.com",
        password: "password",
        role: "test",
    };

accountCtrl.create(account).then((result) => {console.log(result)}).catch((err) => {console.log(err)});
```

Comment: there could be a problem at Account.create(doc). Is the function stated your own custom function?  if so you would probably have to post the implementation code here

Comment: thats the  builtin mongoose function. ModelObject.create()

Comment: what's the error you are getting @Account.create(doc).then().catch(err){reject(err); maybe you can do a console.log(err) at reject(err) so that we can find out more.

Comment: no error is thrown and the program exits with code 0 success.